# jqGrid Set Selected Rows

Tags: jqgrid

I have a jqgrid with `multiselect true` and I want to set some of rows.(I know the row ids.) How can I do that?

I mean opposite of

```
$("#myTable").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow');
```

as like:

```
$("#myTable").jqGrid('setGridParam', 'selarrrow', rowArray);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to loop through the `rowArray` array and call `setSelection` method for every rowid from the `rowArray`:

```
var i, count, $grid = $("#myTable");
for (i = 0, count = rowArray.length; i < count; i += 1) {
    $grid.jqGrid('setSelection', rowArray[i], false);
}
```

Comment: Oleg, This works well if applied for a few row. If I use a for-loop for about 1000 rows, the browser crashes. Is there any way to handle this problem without using for loop?

Answer (score 5):

```
$.each(rowsToSelect, function(_, rowId) {
    $grid.setSelection(rowId, false);
});
```

No much difference. Just seemed neater :)

Comment: or any recent browser: rowsToSelect.forEach(function(rowId){$grid.setSelection(rowId, false);});

Answer (score 2):

(Pretty amazing that even now, in 2014, jqGrid doesn't persist checkboxes when paging..)

Here's the code I needed to use, with jqGrid 4.4.5, to get the checkboxes to set, after moving to a new page:

```
var idsOfSelectedRows = [];   //  list of RowIDs for rows which have been ticked

$("#tblContracts").jqGrid({
      ...   
      colModel: [
          { name: 'AddContract', width: 50, align: "center", editable: true, edittype: 'checkbox', editoptions: { value: "True:False" }, formatter: "checkbox", formatoptions: { disabled: false } },
          { name: "ContractName", search: true, width: 80, align: "center" }
      ],
      loadComplete: function () {
          for (i = 0; i < idsOfSelectedRows.length; i++) {
              $(this).setCell(idsOfSelectedRows[i], 'AddContract', true);
          }
      },
```

During development, I put an "alert" in that "for" loop. I found that using "`setSelection`" simply stepped through my list of RowIDs, selected the row (so it would become highlighted), then moved on to the next, selecting that one instead.

It didn't ever *tick* any of the checkboxes.

Notice that my "setCell" function includes the *name* of the jqGrid column where I have a checkbox.

If you cut'n'paste this code, make sure you change this line to reflect the name of your jqGrid checkbox column.