# Using XML to set the checkbox in jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, checkbox

I have a grid that is being loaded with XML data.  One of the parameters of the XML is a true/false value and I would like to use that value to select the rows that are pre-selected (multiselect:true).

As an example:

```
<rows>
<row><data>338</data><host>foo</host><sent>true</sent></row>
<row><data>485</data><host>bar</host><sent>false</sent></row>
</rows>
```

The checkbox column that I'm referring to is the built-in column that is added as the first column when multiselect is true.  The only reason I haven't dumped it and used a custom checkbox column is that there are a bunch of other routines that act on that column so I would like to keep it if possible.

Answer (score 0):

jqGrid column setup:

```
{ name: 'checked', index: 'checked', 
 editable:true, edittype:'checkbox', editoptions: { value:"True:False"}, 
 formatter: "checkbox", formatoptions: {disabled : false}}
```

Example local data:

```
var data = [
    {id:"66", thingy:"Lemiux", blank:"", number:"66", status:"Retired", checked:"Yes"},
    {id:"99", thingy:"Gretzky", blank:"", number:"66", status:"Retired", checked:"No"}
];
```

Working example on jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/dumbguy5689/9ueDL/

Edit: To deal with the multiselect use the code on this link and then just test the value you pass in the row that contains weather the row should be selected or not. 
[jqGrid Set Selected Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8310339/jqgrid-set-selected-rows)

Comment: Yes, that's the result I got too if I use a custom checkbox, but I'm trying to use the built-in checkbox that comes with jqgrid when you turn on multi-select.

Comment: I beleive the above is the built in check box that comes with jqgrid, aka the `formatter: "checkbox"`

Comment: multiselect: true to see the built-in one that I was referring to.