# jqGrid setselection true not work

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a jgGrid with a list of object, I want to select all rows on load page.
This is my code

```
multiselect: true,
loadComplete: function(){   
     var ids = $("#listDaFatturare").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
     for(var i = 0; i <= ids.length; i++){
        $("#list").jqGrid('setSelection', i, true);
      }
 },
```

But don't run, In my view I see selected only one row. 
I don't understand where is the problem, I try to debug the code and apparently there are no problems.

Any ideas?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8310339/jqgrid-set-selected-rows

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I resolved in this mode:

```
 loadComplete: function(){   
        var i, count, $grid = $("#list");
        var rowArray = $("#list").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
        for (i = 0, count = rowArray.length; i < count; i += 1) {
            $grid.jqGrid('setSelection', rowArray[i], true);
        }
    },
```